# Deciding an EQ's Center Frequencies

Tags: audio, filter-design, equalizer

I am currently making a relatively simple EQ of a music app, for which we decide to have 5 bands. Other than that, we want to have a bass boost knob, which, as I view it, is just another Peak EQ filter — so a 6 band EQ.

- Are there any standards on what a 5(or 6) band EQ's frequencies should be?
- What should the bass boost's frequency be?

Also, we are making only one Q knob to control the Q for all bands, simply because there isn't any space left for more knobs to be added, but we still want to provide this functionality.

- Is this a good practice/design?
- If not, is it at least acceptable or useful?

Comment: Usually you see octave scale used with constant Q 6-band Peaking EQ starting from 100Hz (... 3.2kHz) but, I quess that's not what you would prefer. You could use EqualizerAPO (Windows) for to find those best center frequencies and Q range for your design. https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/ .

Comment: Some useful reading - https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/6/5/129/htm

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preferred_number) might also be of interest.

Comment: Also, as an alternative to a peak filter, a bass boost may also be implemented via a shelving filter.

Comment: True, is a LSHV a more common and better practice for a bass boost? If it is I think I'll opt for it. @applesoup

Answer (score 3):

The audible range is about 10 octaves, and usually the center frequencies of a graphic equalizer would be distributed equally spaced on a log scale to cover that range. Common equalizers have either $30$ bands (with $1/3$ octave filters) or $10$ bands (with $1$ octave filters).

If you want $5$ bands, you could choose filters that cover approximately $2$ octaves. The five center frequencies would then be something like

\begin{matrix}
30\,\text{Hz} & 125\,\text{Hz} & 500\,\text{Hz} &2\,\text{kHz} &8\,\text{kHz}
\end{matrix}

If you have an equalizer like that I'm not sure if an additional bass boost button makes much sense. If you want $6$ frequencies, just divide the $10$ octaves into $6$ equally spaced bands (on a log scale).

Comment: Got it. I'm getting 16-16KHz for the ten octaves (C0-C10), but I know the human audible range is 20-20K. Sounds between 16K-20K is very sharp and not really found in music because its sharpness and may even be considered a noise, so no need to have a band in between 16K-20K. Am I right?

Comment: @Edward: It doesn't matter so much if you take 16kHz or 20kHz as upper limit of the audible range. If you use the range 20Hz-20kHz for your equalizer and you define 5 center frequencies in the way I did in my answer you end up with (approx.): 40,160,625,2500,10000 Hz